How to Run a Python Application with Gunicorn Using Bazel
I'm working on a Python project where I need to use Bazel to manage my builds. I want to run my Python application using gunicorn as the HTTP server. I've already added gunicorn as a dependency in my requirements.txt file. However, I'm not sure how to configure Bazel to use gunicorn as the runner for my application. Can someone provide a clear example or guide on how to set this up?
Here is what I have so far:
requirements.txt:
flask
gunicorn

_pip_parse(
        name = "embeddings_requirements",
        python_interpreter_target = interpreter,
        requirements_lock = "//service:requirements.txt"
)

BUILD.bazel:
load("@aspect_rules_py//py:defs.bzl", "py_binary")

    py_binary(
        name = name,
        srcs = merged_srcs,
        data = merged_data,
        env = binary_env,
        imports = ["src", "."],
        main = main,
        tags = merged_tags,
        toolchains = merged_toolchains,
        visibility = merged_visibility,
        deps = merged_deps
    )


https://gist.github.com/ewhauser/3c6eaaec507e96e068cc6633a3ec135a

I need clarification a bit,
Where are pointing the main //python/wrappers/gunicorn:__main__.py ?
In my case I have this targets for gunicorn package
bazel query "@embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:*" @embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:BUILD.bazel @embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:data @embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:dist_info @embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:gunicorn @embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:pkg @embeddings_requirements//gunicorn:whl 

To run any python script with entrypoint from pip deps need to use py_console_script_binary rule from aspect rules py
  load("@rules_python//python/entry_points:py_console_script_binary.bzl", "py_console_script_binary")

py_console_script_binary(
        name = "my_gunicorn_target",
        script = script, # "gunicorn"
        pkg = pkg, # requirement("gunicorn")
        binary_rule = py_binary,
        deps = binary_deps,
        **kwargs
    )

